# Addthis on dynamic injected html don´t work

Tags: ajax, addthis

I have some pieces of html injected on the fly using AJAX, those pieces have a personalized addthis tags like this:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis-detail" addthis:url="CustomURL" addthis:title="CustomTitle">
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
     <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
```

But i can't get to load the addthis buttons, even if i reinit using:

```
addthis.init()
```

How can i get this done, what i'm missing?

I call the init in my success ajax function handler .

Comment: Here are you adding CustomURL and CustomTitle? Are those variables or placeholders only meant for SO? Also does the CustomURL not work or is addthis not working at all on those pages?

Comment: There are just placeholders for SO. Is addthis the one that does not work, when the dom is loaded in a traditional way it work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote a blog post on this: http://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/05/07/a-brief-history-of-using-addthis-dynamically/

Happy to answer any more questions on this.